# How do I make a fill in the blank with words in-between?

Tags: html

so basically I want to make a fill in the blank with text in-between two inputs but I don't exactly know how

I've tried

```
<input class="fill-out"></input>
<h5 class="nowrap">Test</h5>
<input class="fill-out"></input>
```

But it's still not a straight line with the two boxes and the text in-between both.

What I'm trying to achieve is like a credit card fill out, for example, you type in some numbers and there are let's say a dash in-between then it goes to the next fill in for the next numbers.

Probably a really easy fix to this but I'm just learning html, this being my first attempt at making a simple site.

Comment: Give them "display: inline" css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them around a `div` and add a style to it with property: `display: inline-block`

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
    <input class="fill-out"></input>
    <h5 class="nowrap">Test</h5>
    <input class="fill-out"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Both work, although this one works better for only specific parts of the code.

Comment: Yes adding that style to each item would create problem.