# How to evenly space text with text boxes?

Tags: css, margin, spacing

So I'm making a fill in the blank with text in between (See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312386/how-do-i-make-a-fill-in-the-blank-with-words-in-between)), now I have a problem where I evenly spaced the text in-between with margin-left and margin-right however if I put let's say 1 instead of 0 it looks like 1 : and with 0 it's normal 0: but since 1 is fewer pixels it doesn't look very good, I could always just leave it like that and hope nobody notices but I'd like to probably make it as clean looking as possible.

See for yourself [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdcL9u83)

If not here's the code,

```css
.text1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  margin-right: -22px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.fill-out {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
  width: 13px;
}

#box2 {
  width: 13px;
}

#box3 {
  width: 21px;
}
```

````html
<div>

  <input class="fill-out" id="box1" type="text" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" />
  <span class="text1">:</span>
  <input class="fill-out" id="box2" type="text" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" />
  <span class="text1">.</span>
  <input class="fill-out" id="box3" type="text" placeholder="000" maxlength="3" />

</div>
```
````

Type in only 2's then run again and type in 1's

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: just increase the widths

Comment: and dont give margin to text just set margin 0 to inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using monospaced fonts.

because i don't think you will have the result you want with the default font.

see on wikipedia the difference [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Comment: Worked perfectly, never knew monospace was a thing, but I sure needed it. Thanks!

Comment: monospaced font are commonly used in IDE, terminals and webpages like your one